# How to make a button in ng-repeat open a full url link in ionic and angularfire?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Assuming i am using this in my controller

```
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");
$scope.messages = $firebaseArray(messagesRef);
```

And in my html is

```
 <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
<p>{{ message.user }}</p>
<p>{{ message.text }}</p>
<button href="{{ message.weblink }}">OPEN THIS LINK</button>
```

That {{website.weblink}} for example is www.google.com from my firebase database.

How can i make that button work to open www.google.com using that button because it is not working .

Comment: Did you try ``ng-href=`` instead? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: what problem are you currently having? is it showing the link? also, it would be nice if you set us a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/18)

Comment: Also you could try to use InAppBrowser plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

Comment: @adolfosrs Whenever i press the button nothing happens. No errors on console.

Comment: @tiblu <button class="button button-assertive" ng-href="{{music.downloadlink}}" onclick='window.open(this.href, "_system", "location=yes"); return false;'>Download
 </button>                   Pressing button opens the browser but it's blank.

Comment: @TomislavStankovic Hi i implemented it. see code above but still no luck

Comment: @TomislavStankovic I have updated the code to a simplier one. kindly look at this one.      <button class="button button-assertive" ng-href="http://www.google.com" onclick='window.open(this.href, "_system", "location=yes"); return false;'>Hello
 </button>                       I want it to open for example google.com when i click that button.

Comment: @frank2k16 Try `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Hello</a>`.

Comment: @TomislavStankovic Great! It now navigates to google. Another problem is when i include a variable to it from firebasearray. It seems dont work.  See for example <a class="button button-assertive" ng-href="http://www.google.com/{{mus.title}}" onclick='window.open(this.href, "_system", "location=yes"); return false;'>Hello
 </a>   Assume a value for {{mus.title}} is onecallaway so i want it to load http://www.google.com/onecallaway. any idea?

Comment: @TomislavStankovic or with your code how do i make it work like <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/{{mus.title}}', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Hello</a>  because the result is http://www.google.com%7B%7Bmus.dlink%7D%7D/      and what im expecting is http://www.google.com/onecallaway

Comment: @TomislavStankovic Nevermind my last comments. got it working, never thought had it all the time <a class="button button-assertive" ng-href="{{mus.dlink}}" onclick='window.open(this.href, "_system", "location=yes"); return false;'>Download</a>           Keypoint. is use <a> instead of <button> Cheers! Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, `<a ng-href="">` should be used instead of `<button href="">`.

> **Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute** will make the
>   link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a
>   chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular
>   replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely
>   return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem. - [**ngHref**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the help buddy